# Distribute numbers from range of numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I need to randomly distribute numbers from given range of numbers.
For example - (1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5) needs to be distributed over a range using vba code .
And each number should atleast be distributed once .

Comment: What does "each number should at least be distributed once" mean? Also, what does "randomly distribute numbers from given range of numbers" mean?

Comment: suppose i want to distribute (1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5) in seven cells.
So 1,2,3,4,5 should be distributed once atleast

Comment: You're really not making sense. Changing your description from "each number should at least be distributed once" to "1,2,3,4,5 should be distributed once at least" is just a rewording. It doesn't explain what you're trying to do. Can you please explain, in clear detail, what you need?

Comment: Quick and dirty: remove duplicates from `(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5)` so you get `(1,2,3,4,5)` write them randomly into 5 desired cells and then pick and fill the last 2 of your 7 cells with random picks from `(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5)`. But you will need to start writing code yourself, no one will do all the work for you.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - That won't produce a random arrangement - there would need to be a final random sort. Also, does the OP want to select the final two items from the remaining values or the original set? How should the distribution be formed. The OP hasn't clearly articulated.

Comment: @Enigmativity I know this is not a full solution, I would have had posted it as an answer instead then. But shuffle an array should not be a big deal (you find that several times easily on Google), so I just gave a hint how the "*Each number at least once*" (what I believe is the actual challenge here) could be solved. And yes the question cannot be answered completely because the OP is not clear about some things as you pointed out correctly. Therefore I only gave that hint so the OP has some idea to start and work with.

Comment: random is random - no conditions ... anything that has conditions cannot be random. If the OP provides a set of elements with a weight, a random placement still cannot guarantee that each element is occuring once ... the case that 100x 1 are picked is possible ... that's the thing about "random" ... if this is not wanted then the task has to be formulated more precisely, avoiding the term "random"

Comment: @MikeD "*random is random - no conditions ... anything that has conditions cannot be random*" I cannot conclude with this, because if you say "Random number between 1 and 10" I would still consider that as random and it actually has a condition `1 ≤ r ≤ 10`. So I think one part of the picking is still randomly picking (even if the total result is not random): Pick `n` numbers by condition `A` and then pick additional `k` numbers randomly, and shuffle them to randomize their position. So the picking is partly random and partly by condition, result is not random, but shuffled (random order).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ tend to agree ... then still the problem definition isn't crisp ... could be about "random positioning" then, but if we ask for "random picking from the weighted set" we cannot guarantee that each different element is picked at least once

Comment: @MikeD But we can split the issue in 2 smaller issues to ensure that: ① Pick all unique numbers once. ② Pick the rest randomly. [Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/pcr-coding/436b0099c0de123287dde94a9eb967e8#file-gistfile1-txt) (all without laying numbers back to the picking pool).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Peh is on the money then try this:

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5 };
var take = 7;

var lookup = numbers.ToLookup(x => x);
var random = new Random();
var result =
    lookup
        .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))
        .Concat(lookup.SelectMany(x => x.Skip(1)).OrderBy(x => random.Next()))
        .Take(take)
        .OrderBy(x => random.Next())
        .ToArray();
```